# how to get b2BodyDef from cocos2d world...?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am creating project with different shapes using box2d.. i created a square using the following code.`b2BodyDef bodyDef;
        bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;

```
    bodyDef.position.Set(screenSize.width/2/PTM_RATIO,50/PTM_RATIO);
    bodyDef.userData = sprite;
    _sqrBody = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

    // Define another box shape for our dynamic body.
    b2PolygonShape dynamicBox;
    dynamicBox.SetAsBox(.5f, .5f);//These are mid points for our 1m box

    // Define the dynamic body fixture.
    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape = &dynamicBox; 
    fixtureDef.density = 10.0f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.4f;
    fixtureDef.restitution = 0.1f;
    _sqrFixture = _sqrBody->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);`
```

i want to move this object.How can i move..any code in "cctouches".Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
body->setTransform(myposition, body->getAngle());
```

you can give a custom position in myposition